# Continuous Execution Multiple Functions independently c#

Tags: .net, multithreading

I want to call multiple functions continuously each minute inside a while loop. Even any function execution time takes more than one minute, other functions should not wait for  other functions to complete.
If I write like the below,

```
        while (true)
        {
            if(executebinary) BinaryConversion();
            if(emailvalidation) ValidateEmails();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
```

any delay in function BinaryConversion() will also delayed execution of function ValidateEmails(). Is there any way to run both functions simultaneously?

Comment: Use two `System.Timers.Timer`s.

Comment: Btw, 1000ms is 1 second, not 1 minute.

Comment: Question #1, you have functions A and B. On the first tick, you execute them both, then wait one minute. When the minute is up, A is not done, but B is. I understand you want to execute B regardless if A is done or not, but do you want to start A again, even though A hasn't completed yet, meaning that for a while the old and new copies of A will both execute?

Comment: Question #2, are the two functions related in any way? The code example you've posted will execute `ValidateEmails` *after* `BinaryConversion` has completed. Is this necessary? Or can they just execute simultaneously?

Comment: Question #3: If function A takes 1 minutes 10 seconds to complete, do you want to wait until the "current minute" is up (50 seconds from now) to start A again, or do you want to start A again at once?

Comment: Two functions are entirely different. They have no relation in between. Only I want to excecure them each minute. After successfull excecurion sleeep for one minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Parallel.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx) if you want them to run in parallel:

```
while (true)
{

    Parallel.Invoke(BinaryConversion, ValidateEmails);

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Based on your edit a longer example:

```
namespace CSharp
{
  using System;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      bool executebinary = true;
      bool emailvalidation = false;

      while (true)
      {
        Parallel.Invoke(
          () =>
            {
              if (executebinary)
              {
                BinaryConversion();
              }
            },
          () =>
            {
              if (emailvalidation)
              {
                ValidateEmails();
              }
            });

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
    }

    private static void ValidateEmails()
    {

    }

    private static void BinaryConversion()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Based on your comment both running simultanously without interference from the other:

```
namespace CSharp
{
  using System;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      bool executebinary = true;
      bool emailvalidation = false;

      Parallel.Invoke(
        () =>
          {
            while(true) if (executebinary) BinaryConversion();
          },
        () =>
          {
            while(true) if (emailvalidation) ValidateEmails();
          });
      }
    }

    private static void ValidateEmails()
    {

    }

    private static void BinaryConversion()
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried Parellel.invoke, but if function ValidateEmail is taking 10 minutes to execute, function Binaryconversion is also exucute after 10 minutes. I need execute Binary Conversion in each minute. Even if ValidateEmail is taking 10 minutes to complete.

Comment: Then put the while loop inside the actions.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:
If you are using C# 5 then two ways:

if you create a methods using *async*, you can

Timer: Kick off a timer with 1 minute interval and then call the methods using async & await:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx
or 
As mentioned by nvoigt

In this case you don;t need Thread.Sleep.

If you are using a earlier versions:

You can still use timer and then create a delegate for these methods and then invoke them asynchronously:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301332.aspx

*The reason you might want to avoid thread.sleep is if its a UI application, it would block the thread of a minute, which you want to avoid.*